# Cron Job - Delete old files, but keep files from the first of the month

Tags: unix, cron

I'm currently running successful mysql backups, and, on some sites, I'm deleting files older that 7 days using this command

```
find  /path/to/file -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

What I'd like to do, because I'm paranoid and would still like some archived information, is delete files older than 31 days, but maintain at least one file from each previous month, perhaps spare any file that was created on the 1st of the month.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a script to contain something like this using xargs:

find /path/to/files -mtime +7| xargs -i rm {};

then  add the script to your cron job

Answer (score 0):

The grep is almost right, it only has one space too many. This works (at least for me, I use Debian):

```
rm `find /path/to/file -type f -mtime +7 -exec ls -l {} + | grep -v ' [A-S][a-z][a-z]  1 ' | sed -e 's:.* /path/to/file:/path/to/file:g'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file with these commands:

```
SRC_DIR=/home/USB-Drive
DATE=$(/bin/date "+%4Y%2m%2d%2H%2M")
TIME_STAMP=$(/bin/date --date 'now' +%s)
TIME_CAL=$[$TIME_STAMP-2592000+25200] #last day, 25200 is my GMT+7hour 
TIME_LAST=$(/bin/date --date "1970-01-01 $TIME_CAL sec" "+%4Y%2m%2d%2H%2M")
/bin/touch -t ${TIME_LAST} /tmp/lastmonth
/usr/bin/find -P -H ${SRC_DIR}  ! -newer /tmp/lastmonth -type d -exec rm -r {} \;
```

You can modified last command based on what you want to delete, in this case I want to delete sub-folders in SRC_DIR. With the 'time attribute' more than 1 month ago.

Answer (score -1):

Kind of ugly, but you can try parsing the output of `ls -l`

```
rm `find /path/to/file -type f -mtime +7 -exec ls -l {} + | grep -v ' [A-S][a-z][a-z]  1  ' | sed -e 's:.* /path/to/file:/path/to/file:g'`
```

Or write a script to get the list then run `rm` on them one at a time.

Comment: Didn't seem to work.  It just deleted all files over 31 days old.